# SwiftUI - Make toolbar's NavigationLink use detail view

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigationview, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I'm working on a two-pane SwiftUI app with a sidebar and detail pane in a `DoubleColumnNavigationView`.

I would like to open a `NavigationLink` from the toolbar of the sidebar into the detail pane, as seen in "open from sidebar" in the gif below).

However, the view opens as a stack instead, as seen in "open from toolbar" in the gif below.

Using `isDetailLink(true)` appears to have no effect.

[image: Demo of the issue in question, showing detail view opening in toolbar instead of sidebar.]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Opened from sidebar")) {
                    Text("Open from sidebar")
                }
            }.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            .navigationTitle("Sidebar")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    // This should open in detail pane
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("Opened from toolbar")) {
                        Text("Open from toolbar")
                    }
                }
            }
            Text("Detail pane")
        }.navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the link in the list. Hide it and toggle it active with an isActive @State

Comment: @loremipsum I haven't discovered an easy way to hide a `List` row. Using an `if` statement means the destination needs to be reloaded on every toggle.

Comment: Not an `if` just `.hidden()` and use the `NavigationLink` with `isActive` in the initializer. then you just toggle an `@State`

Comment: `.hidden()` hides row content, not the row itself. Regardless, [Denis's answer using `.background()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68855565/9068081) works perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Universal solution

As you might know, `NavigationLink` doesn't work well when placed in a `toolbar`. What is suggested here - is to place a `Button` into a `toolbar` and use a hidden `NavigationLink` somewhere in the code. The button tells the link to open the detail view and the link does the action. Here is your code adjusted with this suggestion:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    /// A state that tracks whether the link in the toolbar should be opened
    @State var toolbarLinkSelected = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Opened from sidebar")) {
                    Text("Open from sidebar")
                }
            }.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            .navigationTitle("Sidebar")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: { toolbarLinkSelected = true }) {
                        Text("Open from toolbar")
                    }
                }
            }
            .background(
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: Text("Opened from toolbar"),
                    isActive: $toolbarLinkSelected
                ) {
                    EmptyView()
                }.hidden() // The link is not visible to user
            )
            Text("Detail pane")
        }.navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

### iOS / iPadOS only solution

Also, if you only need to support iOS and iPadOS, you can use an older way of implementing it using `navigationBarItems`. This won't work on macOS as this modifier is not available but works well for iOS/iPadOS. Here is the example:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Opened from sidebar")) {
                    Text("Open from sidebar")
                }
            }.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            .navigationTitle("Sidebar")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: NavigationLink(destination: Text("Opened from toolbar")) {
                Text("Open from toolbar")
            })
            Text("Detail pane")
        }.navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a fantastic solution! I hadn't considered `.background()`.